# Spark access data frame from outside foreach batch (Strcutred Streaming)

Tags: apache-spark

I want to create and update a data frame inside the foreach batch of a spark stream and access it outside the foreach batch iterator below is what I am trying to do in spark structured streaming.
Is it possible to access data frames which are created or updated inside foreach batch from outside for each batch in spark structured streaming ?

```
// assign a empty data frame
var df1: Option[DataFrame] = None: Option[DataFrame]

validatedFinalDf.writeStream
  .foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
    println("I am here printing batchDF")
    batchDF.withColumn("extra", lit("batch-df")).show()

    // un presist the data frame if it has data
    if (df1 != None) {
      df1.get.unpersist()
    }

    // assign data to data frame
    df1 = Some(batchDF.withColumn("extra", lit("batch-df-dim")))
}.start()

// access data frame outside foreach not working stale data ....
if (df1 != None) {
      df1.get.show()
}

spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

I cant even access temp tables which are created inside foreach batch from outside for each batch.
Even the data frame which is updated inside foreach batch shows stale data from outside foreach batch.

Thanks
Sri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small work around made the trick , converted batch data frame to in memory stream which was accessed outside foreach batch.

```
case class StreamData(
                      account_id: String,
                      run_dt: String,
                      trxn_dt: String,
                      trxn_amt: String)

    import spark.implicits._
    implicit val ctx = spark.sqlContext
    val streamDataSource = MemoryStream[StreamData]

    source.writeStream
      .foreachBatch { (batchDf: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
        val batchDs = batchDf.as[StreamData]
        val obj = batchDs
          .map(x => StreamData(x.account_id,x.run_dt,x.trxn_dt, x.trxn_amt))
          .collect()

        streamDataSource.addData(obj)
      }
      .start()

    val datasetStreaming: Dataset[StreamData] = streamDataSource.toDS()

    println("This is the streaming dataset:")
    datasetStreaming
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .outputMode("append")
      .start()

spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

Answer (score 1):

The foreachBatch `iterates` over the collection and, if i don't mistake, expect an `effectful` operation (eg writes, print, etc).
However what you do inside the body is to assign a temporary result to an external `var`.

So there the problems:

- conceptually that is wrong because, even if it had worked fine, you would end up with just the `last` Dataframe assigned to your `var`.
- I think you need to `start` the operation as exemplified in the doc [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch)

DF are immutable. If you want to change your DataFrame when use `mapping` functions (eg, `withColumn`) or other transformation API and return the new DF.

When you're satisfied with the result only then persist using the foreach / foreachBatch calls

Comment: ok found a work around using memory stream but more kind a looking for something without collect